# Mocks vs Stubs en PHPUnit

Tags: php, pruebas-unitarias

Como puedo diferenciar en PHPUnit un Stub de un Mock.

Los Stubs verifican estado, y solo se dedican a devolver respuestas concretas cuando se le llama. La documentación de PHPUnit en esto es claro y el ejemplo es muy ilustrativo:

```
    // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
    $stub = $this->createMock(SomeClass::class);

    // Configure the stub.
    $stub->method('doSomething')
         ->willReturn('foo');

    // Calling $stub->doSomething() will now return 'foo'.
    $this->assertEquals('foo', $stub->doSomething());
```

Cuando se llama al método que se configura, devolverá la respuesta que se le indica.

En el caso de los Mocks verifican comportamiento, no están interesados en devolver valores, sino comprobar que se pasa por ciertos métodos, cuantas veces se pasa, etc. Pero en PHPUnit esto no está tan claro, ya que no existen métodos verify() (como existen en otros).

¿Cómo sería la creación de un Mock (que no un Stub) en PHPUnit?

Answer (score 1):

Para configurar un mock, se debe usar el método `expects`, que permite configurar llamadas esperadas a nuestro mock:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder(SomeClass::class)
                 ->setMethods(['metodoEjemplo'])
                 ->getMock();

$mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('metodoEjemplo')
     ->with(1, 2)
     ->willReturn(3);
```

Al igual que al configurar los Stubs, podemos indicar los argumentos que debe recibir la llamada mediante `with`, asi como el valor de retorno que devolverá la llamada mediante `willReturn`.

La configuración de los Mocks tambien está documentada en la web de PHPUnit:

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects